# A couple questions regarding graduate studies

Tags: phd, masters, application, undergraduate, research-undergraduate

I am currently a first year physics undergraduate in a obscure university in a obscure country. My goal is to continue on to obtain a PhD in physics from the best university I possibly can in order to put myself in the best possible network of researchers and academics so I could maximize the quality of my own research. However there are a couple of questions I have.

a) Considering the fact that I've failed my first year at the university and am retaking failed subjects, how is that fact going to affect my prospects of continuing my education (Masters and/or PhD) ?

b) Since it impossible to get research experience as an undergraduate in my country, what can I do to make up for that as an undergraduate?

c) How actually is important undergrad GPA for graduate studies? How are GPA scores interpreted in admissions, meaning what admission officers use them for?

d) Considering that my interests are in theoretical physics, is it really important to be in a high ranking institution, and if so why?

Comment: Everything is built from foundation. You failed the first year and are re-taking failed subjects. I think you should get all A's when re-taking those failed subjects before asking question (b) and (c).

Comment: Please ask [one question per post](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1203/welcome-to-academia-se/1204#1204)! Also, I believe some (maybe all?) of these questions have already been asked and answered on this site, use search to find them.

Comment: See: [How does the admissions process work for Ph.D. programs in the US, particularly for weak or borderline students?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/38237/), [How essential is your GPA for admissions to PhD programs to US universities in Theoretical Physics?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/3499/), [How much will a poor first semester affect my grad school chances?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/34123/), [How handicapped am I in graduate admissions if I graduated from a lower tier university?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/26791/),

Comment: (continued), [What does "university ranking" mean for a graduate admissions committee?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/13061/), [How to improve profile for graduate admissions in mathematics, when coming from a country where quality of math education is poor?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/67048/)

Comment: Right now you are inspired to study physics.  Maybe your interest will continue, maybe not.  Time will tell.  What I do know is that this is a good time to learn how to manage school anxiety.  The skills you learn now will stand you in good stead later if you continue in academia.  // Have you figured out why this first year went so badly, and what sorts of changes would help you do better?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to ensuring that you get high grades on your retake (as stated by scaaahu), I would recommend that you get involved with research projects early on and try to get publications out of them-this might compensate for any poor performances in your undergraduate studies. Since you've mentioned this is impossible in your country, perhaps you might want to try and do this abroad during your holidays. Also it might still be possible for you to attend conferences and submit abstracts or posters. It is not the end of the world if you've failed some courses in your first year. In some universities, the first year doesn't count towards your overall GPA. I would advise that you check this with your university.

Generally speaking, the higher the ranking of the university is, the better your career prospects. Of course, if you work with "important people" or highly respected research groups in your field, it might not matter so much.